# rewrite rule in .htaccess: what does it do

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess

What does this line in .htaccess do, and when would I need it?

```
RewriteRule !.(js|css|ico|gif|jpg|png)$ index.php
```

I'm working with zend and I noticed the .htaccess generated by zend doesn't have this rule, but I've seen a tutorial that has it without explaining why.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a `RewriteRule` redirecting every request *except* requests for those file types (js, CSS, icons, GIF/JPG/PNG graphics) to `index.php`.

It's so that requests for static resources don't get handled by index.php (which is generally a good thing, because starting a PHP instance is expensive.)

It is however already handled in the code block below. This part:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

Excludes the redirection to `index.php` for files that physically exist ( `-s`); symbolic links ( `-`); and existing directories (`-d`).

If you use the second block you quote (the one created by Zend), everything's fine.

[Reference in the Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: do you mean "(-l)" in your answer, and not "(-)" ?

Answer (score 1):

The rule:

```
RewriteRule !.(js|css|ico|gif|jpg|png)$ index.php
```

basically says: "If the request does NOT (!) end ($) with .js/css/ico/giv/jpg/png redirect it to index.php".

You'd need this rule to avoid images/stylesheets and js script requests being passed to index.php.