# Serve static files without hard coding all file types header information

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, static

I am currently making a router in my project and I realised a problem. I am using the .htaccess file to redirect all routes to my `router.php` file. This creates a problem where all of my css/images/js files are redirected to my .htaccess file too. This is the code for my .htacess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +Multiviews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

I had tried solving this problem by manually detecting if it is one of the recognised static file type and manually returning the contents. In my router class, I checked if the give file type is a recognised static file type. If it is a static file type I will render it if not I will give it to the handle function which basically checks if the route is recognised and returns the call to a function.

```php
       if ($isStatic["check"]) {
            $this->render->returnStaticFiles($data["uri"], $isStatic["type"], $isStatic["ext"] ?? "");
        } else {
            $this->handle($data["uri"]);
        }
```

However, the problem with this is I need to manually add the static file types to an array and use a function to set the right headers or else it is just going to be recognised as *text/html* and that doesn't work with either css or images. Css will not get parsed and images will simply return as binary texts as gibberish. This is how I currently implement the render class:

```php
<?php

namespace app\Router;

use JetBrains\PhpStorm\ArrayShape;

class Render
{
    public array $static_file_types = ["js", "css", "html", "json"];
    public array $image_types = ["png", "jpg", "jpeg"];

    public function __construct(
        public string $root_dir = "",
        public string $home = "http://localhost/"
    ){}

    public function throwError(int $statusCode = 500) :string
    {
        $err_dir = $this->root_dir . "errors\\";
        $file_contents = file_get_contents($err_dir . "$statusCode.php") ?? false;
        if (!$file_contents) {
            return str_replace(
                ["{code}", "{home}"],
                [$statusCode, $this->home],
                file_get_contents($err_dir . "err_template.php")
            );
        }
        return str_replace("{home}", $this->home, $file_contents);
    }
    public function returnStaticFiles(string $uri, string $type, string $ext) : void
    {
        if ($type == "cnt") {
            $this->setHeader($ext);
            include_once $this->root_dir . $uri;
        } elseif ($type == "img") {
            $this->handleImage($this->root_dir . urldecode($uri), $ext);
        } else {
            echo "This file is not supported sorry";
            exit();
        }
    }
    private function handleImage(string $path_to_image, string $type) : void
    {
        if (file_exists($path_to_image)) {
            $image = fopen($path_to_image, "r");
            header("Content-Type: image/$type");
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path_to_image));
            fpassthru($image);
        } else {
            echo "This image does not exist sorry";
        }
    }
    #[ArrayShape(["check" => "bool", "type" => "string", "ext" => "string"])]
    public function checkIsStatic($uri) : array
    {
        $_uri = explode(".", $uri);
        $ext = end($_uri);

        if (in_array($ext, $this->static_file_types)) {
            return ["check" => true, "type" => "cnt", "ext" => $ext];
        } elseif (in_array($ext, $this->image_types)) {
            return ["check" => true, "type" => "img", "ext" => $ext];
        } else {
            return ["check" => false, "type" => ""];
        }
    }
    private function setHeader($ext): void
    {
        switch ($ext) {
            case "css":
                header("Content-Type: text/css"); break;
            case "js":
                header("Content-Type: text/javascript"); break;
            case "json":
                header("Content-Type: application/json"); break;
            default:
                header("Content-Type: text/html"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is working just fine but is there any way around this? I might need to serve PDF content or other file types such as audio or video and I don't think this is an optimal solution for it. I tried searching it but I don't think I can find anything.

I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: You're building a complex solution to a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place. You have `RewriteCond` rules to skip actual files and directories from being passed to PHP. Using PHP to serve static assets only adds overhead. Are you positively sure your `.htaccess` file is being used? Are your assets in a public directory?

Comment: Also, you've enabled [Content Negotiation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html). That can get tricky, try disabling it temporarily to ensure it isn't interfering. Last but not least, do you need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`? Are there other PHP scripts apart from your router?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm making my rule to skip actual files as I would not like the directories to be displayed. Example: there's my database handling files and I don't think I want to be serving it to users if they happen to match the url. My .htaccess file is being used I'm sure of it. I don't quite understand what you mean by content negotiation so can you explain it in a little depth? I disabled the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` since I don't need it thanks for pointing it out

Comment: With disabling content negotiation I mean adding  `#` in front of `Options +Multiviews`.

Comment: "I'm making my rule to skip actual files as I would not like the directories to be displayed" - So you actually want PHP to serve assets? Well, I'm not sure now of which of your rules enables that, sorry.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález sorry I didn't say it clear enough. I want static files to be served normally (without going through php) and the rest to the router file. Is it possible with .htaccess? Or do I need something else?

Comment: Your `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` should already be taking care of that.  It is saying that it shouldn't send anything to the router if it is a regular file that exists to be served.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple solve. I just changed the redirect everything to `router.php` into another line `RewriteRule !.(js|css|ico|gif|jpg|png)$ router.php [L]`

This checks if the file is not a js or css or etc then it redirects to router.php file or else it would normally serve the file. I think my question is not clear enough for other people to understand so I hope this answer clears things up.

Big shoutout to this link which made everything right: [rewrite rule in .htaccess: what does it do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739312/rewrite-rule-in-htaccess-what-does-it-do)

Comment: There must be something else going on. You shouldn't need this at all, the rules in the question are already skipping these and any other file. Look for example at the [mod_rewrite rules suggested by Slim framework](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/web-servers.html#apache-configuration), they're essentially what you have. Perhaps there's a conflict with content negotiation or with some undisclosed setting?

Comment: Also, since you're now filtering by URL, you won't be able to use PHP to handle content such as download scripts or dynamically generated pictures.

Comment: I didn't change any settings for my server (xampp localhost) and I found out what the actual problem is. I have put another statement under all those `RewriteCond` which just cancels out the `.php` extension for the files *I actually forgot to remove this so the rewrite conds are not for the `router.php` redirection. When I copied my code I actually ommitted the line* I updated the original question for the part that is messing with everything. Thanks for pointing it out.